# Is Entity Manager cleared automatically after each request?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

Spring is providing one Entity Manager per thread. But I can`t find info if Spring clears Entity Manager after @RestControllers method is finished executing? So for example, if I have a method similar to this

```
    @GetMapping("/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<SomeEntity> someRequest() {
        SomeEntity res = someService.doSomeJpaRelatedWork();
        return new ResponseEntity<>(res), HttpStatus.OK);

    }
```

Will spring call EntityManager.clear() after the request or will Entity Manager keep entities for further requests on that thread?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your method doesn't use an `EntityManager` nor has it `@Transactional` annotation it is completely independent of the `EntityManager` and will on its own not affect any `EntityManager`.

Also, I doubt anything is Spring will call `clear` implicitly.

**BUT** Spring doesn't use one `EntityManager` per `Thread` but one per request. 
So the next request in your web application will get a fresh `EntityManager` with a clear 1st level cache. So while the correct answer for the question you asked is "No, `clear` isn't called", the answer which is probably relevant is "Yes, the `EntityManager` is clear on each call of your controller method."